# Add an image as watermark to a video file with ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I would like to add a text to a video file with FFMPEG. While I was able to do this with plain text

> $FFMPEG -y -i $SOURCE \
>           -vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/Lato-Reg-webfont.ttf:fontsize=40:box=1:boxcolor=black:fontcolor=white:text='$WATERMARK':x=(main_w-text_w)-10:y=(main_h-text_h)-4" \
>           -threads $THREADS -f mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -b $MOBILE_BITRATE -r $MOBILE_FRAME_RATE -strict -2 \
>           -s $RESOLUTION_SD -acodec libfaac -ar $MOBILE_AUDIO_RATE -ac $MOBILE_AUDIO_CHANNELS -ab $MOBILE_AUDIO_BITRATE \
>           $VIDEONAME_MOBILE-android.mp4

this won't look good enough. So I tried with adding a transparent PNG file as a watermark. Looking for examples I tried like this:

> $FFMPEG -y -i $SOURCE \
>           -vf "movie=$WATERMARK_SMALL_PATH [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:main_h/2-overlay_h/2 [out]" \
>           -threads $THREADS -f mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -b $MOBILE_BITRATE -r $MOBILE_FRAME_RATE -strict -2 \
>           -s $RESOLUTION_SD -acodec libfaac -ar $MOBILE_AUDIO_RATE -ac $MOBILE_AUDIO_CHANNELS -ab $MOBILE_AUDIO_BITRATE \
>           $VIDEONAME_MOBILE-android.mp4

it won't work. I can share the exact error output if that could be useful to anyone.

Comment: Have you tried looking here ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135973/how-should-i-add-a-transparent-watermark-png-over-my-rtmp-h264-stream-with-ffmpe

Comment: You need to show the actual, unscripted ffmpeg commands and the complete ffmpeg console outputs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the overlay filter you don't need the `movie=` format. It's easier, so use this format instead:

> `ffmpeg -y -i inputmovie -i inputpicture.png -filter_complex 'overlay=0:0' -s 1280x720 ...other parameters... outputfile.mp4`

The size I put in is as an example only- yours will be different. Note that the size is the same for the picture as well as the movie frame, and no scaling is actually being done here. The `0:0` is for alignment of the picture to the top left of the movie frame- this is logical since they are both the same size.

Comment: A [complex filtergraph](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Complex-filtergraphs) uses one or more inputs and produces one or more outputs, so `-filter_complex` should be used here instead of `-vf`. `-y` is a global option so it should be the first option. The scaling should be in the filtergraph by using the [`scale`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter instead of using `-s`; otherwise it may be ambiguous as to when and where it is being applied.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks. Always used `-filter_complex` because there were other filters in the chain. It was wrong for me to infer that removing other filters from the chain automatically would mean that `-vf` would work. I realize now that there are 2 inputs. Correcting it.

Comment: This could probably be improved upstream since I think using `-filter_complex` works for linear filtering/simple filtergraphs too (but I may be wrong about that and I haven't looked at the code).

Comment: Thank you @Rajib, it worked how you suggested. Anyway, an important detail for is that I needed to also convert the PNG to 8bit using **pngquant**

Comment: @Alex Flo It would be great if you share your full command for everyone's benefit.

Comment: Sure but I am not sure what command you're having in mind? The FFMPEG is the one you suggested + some specific params that I am not sure would be relevant for this issue. I could add the pngquant command but also not sure is relevant in this context.

Comment: @Alex Flo Hey I'm new here too, but I guess everything helps. So Your full command on ffmpeg, as well as the pngquant- if only in a comment. Should benefit others.